# Automatic Updates without FLEXnet Connect

Tags: visual-studio, installshield-le

I have the Limited Edition of InstallShield that comes with the Professional Edition of Visual Studio.

I want to host my updates on my own server, like you can in the ClickOnce Publication settings.

I would like to have the application autoupdate if a newer version is available on the server.

Is this possible? In the Update Notifications I only see 'Yes - Enable FlexNet Connect with Software Manager 12.01' or 'Yes - Enable FlexNet Connect Without Software Manager'. I don't see any way to have it check a personal FTP site for updates as was available in the ClickOnce settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible with IS LE. It is possible by writing your own infrastructure to poll for updates, download and invoke them.

Comment: Good to know. Is there any good documentation on how to do this?

Comment: I've helped one customer do it using a library called wuw4.  Basically I designed the MSI in such a way that it would work and then they made the MSIEXEC calls to invoke it.